# Prometheus C# 6 dotnet - connection refused in Docker

Tags: docker, prometheus, c#-6.0

I am trying to get a .net C# 6 API to remove metrics through to Prometheus, both running inside docker containers.

When I visit http://localhost:9090/targets, it is telling me that "Get "http://myapi:50505/metrics": dial tcp 192.168.65.2:50505: connect: connection refused" (the state is Down).

Within my api container, I did a `netstat --tcp --listen --numeric-ports` expecting that port 50505 would be being listened to, but it wasn't -- just 5005 (and 35605, which I also tried in the prometheus.ym).

I tried adding "50505:50505" to the ports on myapi.

One Google search suggested my C# 6 code should do this:

```
var metricServer = new KestrelMetricServer(port: 1234);
metricServer.Start();
```

So I did that, changed the prometethus.yml to listen for port 1234, still no luck.

I've tried the suggestions out there, including using localhost:50505 in the prometheus.yml, exposing 50505 in my API Dockerfile.

No errors in either the myapi nor prometheus logs.

No luck.

This is my prometheus.yml:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "myapi"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["myapi:50505"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  myapi:
    image: myapi
    container_name: myapi
    ports: 
      - "7109:5005"
    networks:
      - mynet

  prometheus:
    image: prometheus
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    depends_on:
      - myapi
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

I built the prometheus container with this Dockerfile

```
FROM prom/prometheus
ADD ./prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/
```

My API is built with this Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

ARG BUILDCONFIG=RELEASE
ARG VERSION=1.0.0

COPY ["myapi.csproj", "./src/myapi/"]

WORKDIR ./src/myapi/

RUN dotnet publish -c $BUILDCONFIG -o out /p:Version=$VERSION

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /src/myapi/out ./

EXPOSE 5005/tcp
EXPOSE 50505/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapi.dll", "--urls", "http://+:5005"]
```

In my Program.cs I have this:

```
...
app.UseMetricServer(50505, "/prometheus");
app.UseRouting();
app.UseHttpMetrics();

app.Run();
```

And if it matters, in the endpoint method I have this:

```
Counter _eventCounter = Metrics.CreateCounter("API_Events", "Entry Attempts", new string[] { "result" });
_eventCounter.WithLabels("test").Inc();
```

Host OS:  Mac M2 Ventura 13.2.1

Docker: Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue myself and I got it working. Here's what the issue for me was

The endpoint was not set up in the environment variable ASPNETCORE_URLS I had to add an entry for the 9090 port so the Prometheus scraper can access the endpoint. I already had https and http set up on 8091 and 8090 for my Web Api service, but I needed another http entry for the 9090 port

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://*:8091;http://*:8090;http://*:9090
```

I made the change and it all sprung into life. I guess it is obvious when you find it :)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 ways about running Metric Server are independent and shouldn't be used together(it will end running two server that we don't need)

### Way #1 `UseMetricServer` (less preferred as it may expose metrics to the world)

In this case we have to do two things, first it add Middleware to our code to listen handle the request by adding

```cs
app.UseMetricServer(50505, "/metrics");
```

But adding this will not started listening on expected port, to make it happen when we are starting the binary we need to use

```bash
dotnet run myapi.dll --urls 'http://0.0.0.0:5005;http://0.0.0.0:50505'
```

Instead of using `--urls` argument it can be provided using environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS` or since .NET 8 using `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS` ([more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port))

So now when we send request to `curl http://127.0.0.1:50505/metrics` you will get response, but using port `5005` will not work as it's filtered by the Middleware

### Way #2 (new more preferred)

This approach is about running another standalone/independent Kestrel server acting only as Metric Server, to make it work we need some code

```cs
var metricServer = new KestrelMetricServer("0.0.0.0", 50505, "/metrics");
metricServer.Start();
```

In this can we don't need provide additional listening port during start, so just running

```bash
dotnet run myapi.dll --urls 'http://0.0.0.0:5005'
```

As before running `curl http://127.0.0.1:50505/metrics` will respond with all the metrics

---

**Note**: Same as before I prefer to use `0.0.0.0` explicitly instead of `+`(default), because it may causes listening only on ipv6 and it may not working in some cases

**Note 2**: All of the code above requires adding `using Prometheus;` in code and installing [prometheus-net.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/prometheus-net.AspNetCore)